# How to fix a for loop that is skipping some values?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, count, counter

I basically have a date entered in cell N3 and a column (column I) that contains date sorted by date. I am trying to write a code that asks the user to input a date at first. Then the program would look for that date in the column I and delete ALL the rows after the row in which the match was found.

My code is somehow working, but here is my problem. Only a part of the rows under the wanted row are being deleted and not all of them. I was thinking that could be an issue with the for-loop or the counter? 
Please let me know if you could help :)

```
Sub DeleteAllRowsPaymentTooFar()

Worksheets("Master").Activate

Dim date_max As Date
date_max = InputBox("What is the maximum date to filter? ")



Range("N3").Value = date_max
Range("N3").NumberFormat = ("ddddd, mmmmmmmmm d, yyyy")


Dim i As Long
i = Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row
Dim result As Integer
Dim str1 As String, str2 As String
Dim counter As Long



str1 = Cells(3, 14).Text

counter = 4

Do While counter <= i

str2 = Cells(counter, 9).Text

result = StrComp(str1, str2, vbTextCompare)

  If result <> 0 Then
 MsgBox ("The date is not yet reached.")

  Else

        For K = counter To i
        Worksheets("Master").Rows(K).EntireRow.Delete
        Next


    End If

counter = counter + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

I expect to remove all the rows under the row where the match was found.

Comment: Why don't you use something like this instead: `Worksheets("Master").Range(counter, i).EntireRow.Delete` to replace any need for a `For` loop

Comment: i think u arent refering the correct sheet. use a with Worksheets("Master") , and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

```
For i=LastPoint To FirstPoint Step-1

    Worksheets("Master").Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

Next i
```